# Transfer operation in eztz js

Tags: node, tezos-client

Can anyone guide me how transfer operation performed in java script?

I am using this function but i can`t transfer from one address to another. 
eztz.rpc.sendOperation(from, operation, keys)

Kindly guide me!

Answer (score 0):

The sender address must be revealed before it can send. Make sure you are revealing the address. Check the eztz documentation for the reveal function.

Comment: I searched in documentation of eztz. But reveal function is not there.

Comment: A very quick scan of the code says it should reveal automatically. Do you have enough funds to pay for the reveal + transaction cost?